# Mysql query to get second and third least value using group by other column value in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My sql query to get middle row values using GROUP BY function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433948/my-sql-query-to-get-middle-row-values-using-group-by-function)

My database structure is like

```
Id     Price     Code
1      0.12      93
2      0.13      93
3      0.54      93
4      0.96      93
5      0.10      94
6      0.30      94
7      0.90      94
8      1.40      94
9      2.30      94
```

I have to fetch the data using `GROUP BY` code and i want the second least row as output.
In the above example i want the output as

```
Id     Price     Code
2      0.13      93
6      0.30      94
```

and in other case i want the third least value and output should be

```
Id     Price     Code
3      0.54      93
7      0.90      94
```

Comment: This is not the duplicate in the last one i need the middle values among all the values but in this case i need the second and third least value

Comment: Strawberry because i want the 2nd and 3rd least value cming for a single code like if i have 10 values of price related to same code i want the 2nd and 3rd least value

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the second value

```
SELECT MAX(Price), Code
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Price, Code
    FROM   TableName
    WHERE 
    (
       SELECT  COUNT(*) 
       FROM    TableName as f
       WHERE   f.Code = TableName.Code and 
               f.Price <= TableName.Price
    ) <= 2                                // << just change this value
) s
GROUP BY Code
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*second*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d607/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*third*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d607/3)